# How to load Data from Database to Datalist control on onmouseover event of asp:button

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am devloping Asp Web Application i have div as shown in Image sub div will open onmouseover.

[image]

i want to load data on onmouseover event of button. i am not able to find any code to load data from database on mouse over Is there any way to do solve it  ?

I tried this  code but it shows                                                  **"<%#Container.DataItem("CustomerName")%>" " Non-invocable member 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItem.DataItem' cannot be used like a method."**

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script>
    $('#Button1').on('mouseover',
       function{
           SqlConnection  dbconn= New SqlConnection("Provider=System.Data.SqlClient;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=ElectricalStrings_beta;Trusted_Connection = True;")
           dbconn.Open()
           sql="SELECT * FROM Feedback";
           SqlCommand dbcomm = New SqlCommand(sql,dbconn)
           SqlDataReader dbread=dbcomm.ExecuteReader()
           customers.DataSource=dbread
           customers.DataBind()
           dbread.Close()
           dbconn.Close()
           });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
<div id ="menu">
    <asp:Repeater ID="customers" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table border="1" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <th>Companyname</th>
                    <th>Contactname</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><%#Container.DataItem("CustomerName")%></td>
                <td><%#Container.DataItem("CustomerMobileNo")%></td>
                <td><%#Container.DataItem("Feedback")%></td>
                <td><%#Container.DataItem("Status")%></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>

        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
   </div>
   </form>
   </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First u need to include the [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) library in your html. Her after you can write in javascript:

```
<script>
$('<class on which you want the mouseover to occur>').on('mouseenter',
function{<here you can load a request to the data base>});
</script>
```

I'm not very familier with ASP but found some documentation on how to access a data base with it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_dbconnection.asp)

Comment: sry I have not a good understanding about ASP.NET all I know is that the function will execute when you do a mouseenter